# remove session array element

Tags: php, html, arrays, session

How can I fetch the indexing to delete a session array element. 
i want to delete Service 'game2' and associated price 2000 by clicking 'click to remove'

// in File A

```
<?php

$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "1000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 1";
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "2000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 2";
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "3000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 3";
$_SESSION['cart']['prices'][] = "4000";
$_SESSION['cart']['services'][] = "game 4";
?>
```

// in file B

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <th style="width: 450px; text-align:center;">Services< /th>
    <th style="width: 450px; text-align:center;">Price< /th>
    <th style="width: 450px; text-align:center;">Delete item< /th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

<?php

foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['services'] as $key => $service) { 
    echo "< tr>< td>".
         $service.
         "< /td>< td style='text-align:center;'>".
         $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][$key].
         "< /td>< td>ckick to remove< /td>< /tr>"; 
} 
?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

user [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on `$_SESSION['cart']['services']`

```
$key = array_search( 'game2', $_SESSION['cart']['services'] );
/* And remove the associated price */
unset( $_SESSION['cart']['prices'][ $key ] )
```